# Checking TokenBalance of other token contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I try to simply check a users DAI token balance on Kovan testnet (ContractAddress: 0xC4375B7De8af5a38a93548eb8453a498222C4fF2) with the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract ERC20 {
  function balanceOf(address who) constant returns (uint256);
}

contract myTest {

  ERC20 myToken;

  function setToken(address tokenAddress) {
    myToken = ERC20(tokenAddress);
  }

  function getTokenBalanceOf(address h0dler) constant returns (uint balance) {
    return myToken.balanceOf(h0dler);
  }
}
```

When exucting the getTokenBalanceOf function Remix throughs an error:

*"call to myTest.getTokenBalanceOf errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.  Debug the transaction to get more information.  "*

[image]

Comment: can you share more details on issue you are facing?

Comment: I get the following error message when executing gtTokenBalanceOf function: ""call to myTest.getTokenBalanceOf errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information. ". Also added a screenshot to post

Comment: Your code could not possibly compile, since function `balanceOf` is not implemented! Also note that in function `getTokenBalanceOf`, you're not doing anything with variable `balance`, so you may as well remove it.

Comment: @goodvibration what do you mean by balanceOf is not implemented?

Comment: I mean: `function balanceOf(address who) constant returns (uint256);` is not implemented. But I apologize, it actually will compile and can run correctly if that function is implemented by the contract deployed at `0xC4375B7De8af5a38a93548eb8453a498222C4fF2`. I suggest that you verify that this function is actually implemented there, and that it doesn't revert for some other reason.

Comment: It seems you are not connecting to the correct blockchain. Your screenshot shows "Javascript VM" in Environment. If you use MetaMask to connect to Kovan it will display "Injected web3" and "Kovan(42) network" below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Make Sure that you are calling function `getTokenBalanceOf()` after
>   the call `setToken()` function. hope this will help you.

Comment: Thats how I did it, and just tried again. Same error message

Comment: I write this answer because it is perfectly run well without any error.

Comment: Just tested it with the old Remix UI and was working there. Really strange

Comment: yup, also me too.